# Android websocket connection failure

Tags: android, sockets, websocket

I'm developing a simple application that's just supposed to connect to a websocket server and send a simple text message. Im using [nv-websocket-client](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client) as the library for the websocket. I can't seem to connect to the server. I've used wireshark to determine that no data is being recieved by the device and no data is coming in through any of the ports i've used so i'm left with the fact that there's something wrong with the application.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    private static final String SERVER = "ws://192.168.2.177:80";
    private static final int TIMEOUT = 5000;
    WebSocketFactory factory = new WebSocketFactory();
    WebSocket ws;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void connectWebsocket(View view) throws IOException{
        ws = factory.createSocket(SERVER);
        try{ws.connect();}
        catch (OpeningHandshakeException e){
            Log.d("OpeningHandshake", "Hello");
        }
        catch (WebSocketException e1){
            Log.d("WebsocketException",e1.getError().toString());
        }
    }
    public void sendMessage(View view){
        ws.sendText("Sending Message...");
    }
}
```

That's my Main activity.
And here's my layout.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.company.websockettest.MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Socket Test" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Press to connect"
            android:onClick="connectWebsocket"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Press To send"
            android:onClick="sendMessage"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

I'm getting a SOCKET_CONNECT_ERROR. And the documentation for the library doesn't seem to give me much on the error itself. Thanks for any help I could get.

Comment: Remove ws:// from SERVER.

Comment: I've tried that. I also get an error as follows. " Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in scheme at index 0: 192.168.2.177:8000"

Answer (score 0):

1. Why don't you register a `WebSocketListener` before calling `connect()` method?
2. When is your `connectWebsocket(View)` method called? Make sure that `connectWebsocket(View)` is called before `ws.sendText("Sending Message...")`. In other words, make sure that a WebSocket connection is established before you send a message to a server.